# puppet compare string in the erb template

Tags: ruby, puppet, erb

We have puppet version 3.8.7. I have the facter that return the version of dovecot: 2.2 or 2.3. In the erb-template I have the next construction:

```
# SSL/TLS protocols to use
111 <% if @dovecot_version =~ "2.2" -%>
112 ssl_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
113 
114 # Diffie-Hellman parameters length
115 ssl_dh_parameters_length = 2048
116 <% else -%>
117 ssl_min_protocol = SSLv3
118 
119 # Diffie-Hellman parameters length
120 #ssl_dh_parameters_length = 2048
121 <% end -%>
```

After apply I see the next error message:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Failed to parse template cpanel/dovecot.conf.erb:
  Filepath: org/jruby/RubyString.java
  Line: 1730
  Detail: type mismatch: String given
at /etc/puppet/environments/testing/modules/cpanel/manifests/dovecot.pp:34 on node server1.development.local
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Whats wrong with variable type? How I can compare the strings? Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby's `=~` operator is for matching strings to regular expressions.  The operands may appear in either order, but one needs to be a regex.  In your case, both are strings.

To compare strings for equality, use the ordinary `==` or `!=` operator.

Comment: I've tried to use `==` or `!=` and it also not working.

Comment: @AndriiK., the answer to the question you posed, "Whats wrong with variable type? How I can compare the strings?" is exactly what I have presented.  Therefore, if using `==` in place of `=~` leaves you with errors, and especially if it leaves you with *the same* error, then perhaps you have asked the wrong question.  In that case, I suggest updating your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I tested and @JohnBollinger's answer is correct. I reproduced both the type mismatch error and confirmed changing to `==` fixes the issue.